# ManyToMany in Spring JPA deleting previous records

Tags: jpa, many-to-many

Hi I'm trying to develop petclinic application using HSQLDB,Spring,Webflow & JSF.

In which Vets and Specialities entities in BusinessEntities layer has ManyToMany relation as follows.

**Vets.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VETS", schema = "PUBLIC", catalog = "PUBLIC")
public class Vets implements BaseEntity, java.io.Serializable {

private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Set<Specialties> specialtieses = new HashSet<Specialties>(0);

public Vets() {
}

public Vets(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Vets(Long id, String firstName, String lastName,
        Set<Specialties> specialtieses) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.specialtieses = specialtieses;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", length = 30)
public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

@Column(name = "LAST_NAME", length = 30)
public String getLastName() {
    return this.lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "VET_SPECIALTIES", schema = "PUBLIC", catalog = "PUBLIC", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "VET_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SPECIALTY_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
public Set<Specialties> getSpecialtieses() {
    return this.specialtieses;
}

public void setSpecialtieses(Set<Specialties> specialtieses) {
    this.specialtieses = specialtieses;
}

}
```

**Specialties.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SPECIALTIES", schema = "PUBLIC", catalog = "PUBLIC")
public class Specialties implements BaseEntity, java.io.Serializable {

private Long id;
private String name;
private Set<Vets> vetses = new HashSet<Vets>(0);

public Specialties() {
}

public Specialties(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Specialties(Long id, String name, Set<Vets> vetses) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.vetses = vetses;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "NAME", length = 80)
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "VET_SPECIALTIES", schema = "PUBLIC", catalog = "PUBLIC", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SPECIALTY_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "VET_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
public Set<Vets> getVetses() {
    return this.vetses;
}

public void setVetses(Set<Vets> vetses) {
    this.vetses = vetses;
}

}
```

And when I add vets object with specialities using setSpecialtieses method, the vets,specialities and vet_secialities tables are populated but the previous relations are getting loss, let me put in this way.

Adding vet with ID 1

```
 --------------        -----------------           --------------------
|   Vets        |     |   Specialities  |         |  vet_specialities  |
| --------------|     |-----------------|         |--------------------|
| ID    Name    |     | ID    Name      |         |Spe_ID      Vet_ID  |
| --------------|     |-----------------|         |--------------------|
| 1     ABC     |     | 1    Surgery    |         |  1          1      |
 --------------       | 2    Radiology  |         |  2          1      |
                       -----------------           --------------------
```

And when I add another Vet object with ID 2,

```
 --------------        -----------------           --------------------
|   Vets        |     |   Specialities  |         |  vet_specialities  |
| --------------|     |-----------------|         |--------------------|
| ID    Name    |     | ID    Name      |         |Spe_ID      Vet_ID  |
| --------------|     |-----------------|         |--------------------|
| 2     ABC     |     | 1    Surgery    |         |  1          2      |
 --------------       | 2    Radiology  |         |  2          2      |
                       -----------------           --------------------
```

Here my previous entries gets deleted and new are getting stored, my requirement is to preserve older vets entries too.

And I have vetsPage.xhtml in which I have One textbox with submit button and corresponding vets.xml flow on entry of which creates new vetsVO object and save it in List using JPA and this moment the Specialities set is null and in same way I have specialitiesPage with one textbox and submit button with corresponding flow which also creates SpecialitiesVO object and save in List and now I have one more page i.e., vetsSpecialitiesPage where I will choose one vetsVO object from dropdown list and map specialities with it and save. By this its saving properly but overriting existing relations.
 Tried couple of suggestions, i.e., using of mappedBy,CascadeType.MERGE etc.. but none give desired result.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: setSpecialtieses takes a collection and seems to replace what is there with the new collection.  If you are passing in a collection with a single value in it, it replaces what is there, wiping out the current state for the new one.  If that is the case, you need to add to the existing collection, not replace it.  ALso note that your two entities have to independent M:M mappings using the same Join table. You might try making one mappedby the other using ManyToMany(mappedby="specialtieses", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  so that it is a true bidirectional relationship

Comment: Dear Chris thanks for your help.Please look into query now as I have edited which should now give big picture.

Comment: sorry, the change doesn't add any more detail as to what you are doing to add a Specialties to a Vet.  Is the Vet's specialtieses collection empty when you add a Specialties to it, then call merge? Makes sure both sides are read in from the EM and are not empty shells with an id which is a common mistake. Also as mentioned, you do not have a bidirectional relationship.  Try fixing the relationship, as changes to one side might overwrite or conflict with changes to the other in its current form.

Comment: Done with changes suggested for bidirectional relationship and by the way the ids in both the tables are auto generated with increment , moreover I cant rely on merge.lets assume I have 1 vetsVO with empty collection and for first instance merge is okay how about I want to change inside of vetsVO collection to new one? my requirement states to stick with setters and gettets and even now it aint working.

Comment: So you are replacing the collection that has a single entity in it, with another collection with a single but different entity?  Merge will merge the state into the managed entity; it is not specific to a single collection.  At the end of the merge, the managed entity will have the same state as the instance you passed in - so it will have a collection refunding a single entity, as is shown in your database.  Call getSpecialtieses().add(speciality) instead of replacing the collection, or add a method to Vets to add it for you